# enum list return null in another enum java

Tags: java, list, enums

There are two enums. These point each other by instance field. But one of them point the other in List. For example;

```
public enum EnumA {
    A1(1, Arrays.asList(EnumB.B1, EnumB.B2)),
    A2(2, Arrays.asList(EnumB.B3, EnumB.B4));

    private int num;
    private List<EnumB> enumBList;

    private EnumA(int num, List<EnumB> enumBList) {
        this.num = num;
        this.enumBList = enumBList;
    }

    public List<EnumB> getEnumBList() {
        return enumBList;
    }
}



public enum EnumB {
    B1(1, EnumA.A1),
    B2(2, EnumA.A1),
    B3(3, EnumA.A2),
    B4(4, EnumA.A2);

    private int num;
    private EnumA enumA;

    private EnumB(int num, EnumA enumA) {
        this.num = num;
        this.enumA = enumA;
    }

    public EnumA getEnumA() {
        return enumA;
    }

}
```

When I tried to obtain "List EnumBList", it was null and I had NPE.

Like:

```
EnumA.A1.getEnumBList();
EnumB.B1.getEnumA().getEnumBList();
```

Comment: I guess you could see that like the "Chicken or the egg" problem ;)

Comment: Well, they have a circular dependency and can't exist at the same time when being initialized. One enum is created before the other, and therefore still points to `null`.

Comment: it is the initializing  problem. i solved by using abstract method. thank you.